# Why do CefSharp custom context menu commands not work most of the time?

Tags: wpf, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I implemented a custom context menu for CefSharp based on [this example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/acef4ab2c3c4b270f79a3f5eaf8135d7699bb486/CefSharp.Wpf.Example/Handlers/MenuHandler.cs) from the CefSharp github page, to get around the issue that events are fired in different threads which resulted in the context menu not closing when clicking outside.

I basically copy pasted it from the original source, just added a few more cases for the commands and it seemed to work at first. However the commands are executed only sometimes (most of the time not).

I added some `Console.WriteLine()` to the code to check what was going on and it seems that the execution of the command is sometimes canceled before it's finished.

I'm not sure if it is a bug in CefSharp or CEF, or if the example implementation is just incomplete. I tried to remove the `menu.Closed` handler, just as an experiment but it seem to make no difference.

I searched the internet but couldn't find a bug that matches the description so I guess it's me. Unfortunately I have a hard time wrapping my head around this. If someone could point me in the right direction, or point out the mistake, that would be nice.

My code so far is basically the same as [this example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/acef4ab2c3c4b270f79a3f5eaf8135d7699bb486/CefSharp.Wpf.Example/Handlers/MenuHandler.cs) but with all cases for the commands.

I created a simple test application that is nothing but a Window with the Browser but the issue persists, although it happens less frequent. The Visual Studio Project I created for testing can be downloaded [here](http://www.filedropper.com/browsertest).

If you try to copy a paste a word a few times with the context menu, you should see that it only works about 70% of the time. I guess it happens less often as in my actual app because my actual application is a big monster compared to the test app, and therefore slower.

[image]

Cef is version 3.3396.1786
CefSharp.Wpf is version 67.0.0
OS: Win10 x64

Comment: Does the problem reproduce in the current supported version?  At time of writing that's 71.0.0

Comment: @amaitland yes, it seems to be. I updated CefSharp.Wpf and its dependencies with Nuget but it didn't change the odd behaviour. I try it in a clean test environment as soon as I can, to rule out that it's my application.

Comment: @amaitland I created a new project to make sure the issue is not related to my current one and could successfully reproduce the behavior. In the test app it doesn't happen as often as in my actual project but I guess it's because the test app runs much faster due to the small size and being nothing than the browser. The Visual Studio project I created can be downloaded here http://www.filedropper.com/browsertest
If you try to copy and paste a word a few times via context menu you should see that it works only about 7 out of 10 times.

Comment: How does the CefSharp.Wpf.Example app behave? What are the list of steps to reproduce?  Is a specific url required? It is only example code, I personally haven't tested it for a long time,

Comment: @amaitland  If you use my linked example project, simply browse to any page where you can use the context menu, it's easiest to reproduce if you have an input field. just try to copy and paste with the context menu some text you previously typed into the input or text area several times . You will notice that sometimes the commands are not executed (context menu closes without anything happening). Can be tested with any other context menu command too (like select all) but i find pasting something shows it best. You open context menu, select "paste", it pastes, you repeat, some times nothing.

Comment: @amaitland I added a video to my question to illustrate the issue. you can see that "Einfügen", which is Paste, only works half of the time. Sometimes it works more often and other times less often. Same is true for every other entry of the custom context menu.

Comment: Looks like you have done some debugging,  what did you work out?

Comment: @amaitland it appears that the command is canceled before it get's executed but it doesn't happen in the `menu.Closed` handler as removing the canceling logic doesn't change anything. As far as I can tell `callback.IsDisposed` is always `false`. Either the `MenuItem`'s command is not executed in the first place or it is canceled halfway through. The `RelayCommand`s are correctly added to the menu item's Command property.

Comment: @amaitland never mind, It looks like I found the solution. `RelayCommand`'s constructor has an additional parameter `keepTargetAlive` which defaults to `false` i set it to `true` and now it seems to work perfectly. So, the issue is not with CefSharp itself but maybe this could be added to the custom menu handler example.

Comment: Pull requests welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not CefSharp or Chromium. The Example uses `RelayCommand` for the MenuItem commands which has a parameter `keepTargetAlive`. The parameter is set to `false` by default. Adding `true` as an argument solves it and the commands are always executed.

Example:

```
menu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
{
    Header = item.Item1.Replace("&", "_"),
    IsEnabled = item.Item3,
    Command = new RelayCommand(() =>
    {
        map_browser_functions(browser, parameters, item);
    }, keepTargetAlive: true)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the RelayCommand isn't enough. (paste in pdf forms)
Solved by using dispatcher:

```
menu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
{
   Header = item.Item1.Replace("&", "_"),
   IsEnabled = item.Item3,
   Command = new RelayCommand(() =>
   {
      Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
      {
         switch (item.Item2)
         {
            case CefMenuCommand.Back:
            {
               browser.GoBack();
               break;
    //...
```